# Two Join Statements

Tags: mysql

So I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(b.friend_id) AS possible_id
FROM friend_friends a
    JOIN friends_friends b 
      ON b.user_id = a.friend_id
WHERE a.user_id = 1703122278
```

It retrieves the **friends of friends** of a specific user.

I have another database that contains data on people who have said they are NOT friends.

Here is the query to get the list of said not friends:

```
SELECT friend_id
FROM friends_not_friends
WHERE user_id = 1703122278
AND not_friends = 1
```

Then I compare the list of not friends, from the list of possible friends and remove the not friends from the list.

How can I combine these two queries without using a sub-query but rather using Joins?

Comment: what is wrong with using sub-queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(b.friend_id) AS possible_id
FROM friend_friends a
  JOIN friends_friends b 
    ON b.user_id = a.friend_id
  LEFT JOIN friends_not_friends n
    ON b.friend_id = n.friend_id
      AND n.user_id = a.user_id
      AND n.not_friends = 1
WHERE a.user_id = 1703122278
  AND n.friend_id IS NULL
```

This shows the

```
(1st list of friends of friends of 1703122278)
MINUS
(2nd list of not friends of 1703122278)
```

I hope you don't want the

```
list of friends of
   (friends of 1703122278
    minus
    (2nd list of not friends of 1703122278)
   )
```

---

Just fooling around, here are the queries using `NOT IN`.
I personally find these more clear, however they may be less efficient regarding speed.

```
-- Friends of friends of a user
SELECT DISTINCT(b.friend_id) AS possible_id 
FROM friend_friends b                      -- the b and a aliases
WHERE b.user_id IN                         -- can be removed 
  ( SELECT a.friend_id
    FROM friends_friends a
    WHERE a.user_id = 1703122278
  )
;
```

and the asked one:

```
-- Friends of friends of a user that  
-- are also not not_friends of the user:
SELECT DISTINCT(b.friend_id) AS possible_id  
FROM friend_friends b                      -- the b, a and n aliases
WHERE b.user_id IN                         -- can be removed too
  ( SELECT a.friend_id
    FROM friends_friends a
    WHERE a.user_id = 1703122278
  )
  AND b.friend_id NOT IN 
  ( SELECT n.friend_id
    FROM friends_not_friends n
    WHERE n.user_id = 1703122278
      AND n.not_friends = 1
  )
;
```

Comment: This one worked great. Only thing was I changed AND n.user_id = 1703122278 to n.user_id = a.user_id. Simplified it a little bit. Thanks!

Comment: thnx. I changed my answer too. Please check that you do want what the query gives and not something like `list of friends of (friends minus notfriends)`

Answer (score 1):

in oracle i would use MINUS operator.

i thik there is a correlary function in mysql - probably a left join or NOT IN clause

Answer (score 1):

Here an solution that filters the "not friends" on  *both levels*  (it filters the not-friends of the user *and* the not-friends of the friends of the user):

```
  SELECT
     DISTINCT(b.friend_id) AS possible_id
  FROM
     friend_friends a
     JOIN friend_friends b ON b.user_id = a.friend_id
     LEFT JOIN friends_not_friends nfa
         ON a.friend_id = nfa.user_id and nfa.not_friends = 1
     LEFT JOIN friends_not_friends nfb
         ON b.friend_id = nfb.user_id and nfb.not_friends = 1
  WHERE
     a.user_id = 1703122278
     AND nfa.friend_id IS NULL
     AND nfb.friend_id IS NULL
```

The "trick" is to do an `LEFT JOIN` and check if there is no data (`NULL`).

By the way - is there an reason that you want no subselect? Sometimes the `LEFT JOIN`-way is faster, but sub-select are often an good choice.

Comment: +1 for you last comment. I would add that (3rd option) a `NOT IN` solution is usually more clear code.

Answer (score 0):

Try a left outer join to the `friend_not_friends` table (matching on friend_id, filtering on user_id and the not_friends flag) and then eliminate rows where there was a matching row from `not_friends` (that is, eliminate rows where the not_friend id is NOT NULL)

```
SELECT DISTINCT(f.friend_id) AS possible_id
  FROM friend_friends a
  JOIN friends_friends f
    ON f.user_id = a.friend_id
  LEFT
  JOIN friends_not_friends n
    ON n.user_id = a.user_id
   AND n.friend_id = f.friend_id
   AND n.not_friends = 1
 WHERE a.user_id = 1703122278
   AND n.user_id IS NULL
```

The trick is filtering out the rows that matched, leaving the rows that did not find match in the `friends_not_friends` table. It's the last predicate in the query (n.user_id IS NULL) that does that filtering for you.

---

Absent the requirement not to use a subquery, then something like this would work as well:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(f.friend_id) AS possible_id
   FROM friend_friends a
   JOIN friends_friends f 
     ON f.user_id = a.friend_id
  WHERE a.user_id = 1703122278
    AND NOT EXISTS 
        ( SELECT 1 
            FROM friends_not_friends n 
           WHERE n.friend_id = f.friend_id
             AND n.user_id = a.user_id
             AND n.not_friends = 1
        )
```